# How to display the uploaded images

Tags: vue.js

### Want to achieve

I use Vue.js for development.
I'm creating a movement to upload an image and display it on the screen.
I was able to do most of it, but when I do the following movements, the image does not appear on the screen.

##### What to do if the image does not show up

###### 1. Initial

[image]

###### 2. Click the upload button to upload the image.

[image]

###### 3. Click the remove button to delete the image.

[image]

###### 4. I clicked the upload button and uploaded the same image, but the image did not show up.

[image]

##### I want to display the image that I have successfully selected in step 4 here, but the image does not show up.

I would like to ask for your wisdom.

### Code

Form.vue

```
<template>
  <div @dragover.prevent="onArea" @drop.prevent="dropFile" @dragleave.prevent="offArea" @dragend.prevent="offArea">
    <img v-if="company.uploaded_image"
         :src="company.uploaded_image"
    />
    <img v-else
         src="~images/default.png"
    />
    <div>
      <button @click="remove" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete"><i class="fas fa-times"></i>remove
      </button>
      <label class="btn"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i>upload
        <input type="file" @change="onFileChange">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  props: {
    company: Object
  },
  onFileChange(e) {
    this.company.image_attributes.filename = ''
    const files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
    this.createImage(files[0]);
    this.company.new_image_name = files[0].name;
    this.company.image_size = files[0].size;
  },
  createImage(file) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = e => {
      this.company.uploaded_image = e.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  },
  remove() {
    this.company.uploaded_image = false;
    this.company.image_attributes.filename = '';
    this.company.uploaded_image = '';
    this.company.new_image_name = '';
    this.company.image_size = '';
  },
  dropFile(e) {
    this.onFileChange(e)
    this.offArea()
  },

  onArea() {
    this.inArea = true
  },
  offArea() {
    this.inArea = false
  },
}
</script>
```

### Environment

Vue.js 2.6
Ruby 2.6
Ruby on Rails 6.0

Answer (score 3):

You can use `URL.createObjectURL(files[0])` generating url.

codepen - https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/oNeeWWY

Comment: thankyou!I've tried to operate the codepen demo you wrote, but I'm having the same problem I'm having now: it doesn't behave correctly in the codepen demo?

Comment: @katahik what is your browser and what's its version? The example codepen is working perfectly on my end

Comment: @Patel Pratik Browser version is GoogleChrome 94.0.4606.81 (Official Build)

Comment: @patel Pratik After uploading an image, delete that image. After that, I want to upload the same image again and display it on the screen, can I do that? I could not do it.

Comment: It's not working for some reason. but the preview one is working